# Converting CSV data to datetime format

Tags: powershell

I'm still learning Powershell and in order to complete an assignment I need to convert written data in CSV files to a powershell accepted datetime format.

The dates in the CSV format are written as: 1-1-2014.

In order to convert them I found out (through a bit of brute force) that I can use the following code:

```
$Files = gci $Source\*.csv 

$Data = Import-CSV $Files -Delimiter ";"

$Data | ForEach-Object { $_.Time = $_.Time -as [datetime] 
$_ 
}
```

However, it would seem to me that this should work as well when written as follows:

```
$Data | ForEach-Object { $_.Time = $_.Time -as [datetime] $_ }
```

When I run it like that it returns a bunch of errors.

The `$_` after `[datetime]` I also only added because a colleague used that in his functions, I don't really understand why it has to be put there, and why it needs to be put on a new line. Could anyone explain? If there is a different/better way to convert CSV data to a datetime format I'd be interested in hearing those as well, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `;` in place of line breaks as a statement terminator. `... -as [datetime];$_`

Comment: `$_.Time =` is updating the object's `Time` property and produces no output, `$_` after that assignment is needed to produce the output of the updated object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first (multi-line) version works because PowerShell interprets a line-break after a complete statement as a *terminator* - it knows that `$_` is a separate statement from `$_.Time = $_.Time -as [datetime]`.

To place multiple separate statements on a single line, you'll have to use a semicolon `;` to separate them:

```
$Data | ForEach-Object { $_.Time = $_.Time -as [datetime]; $_ }
```

Comment: That answers one question, thanks! But why is it even neccessary to add $_ after the [datetime]? Why isn't { $_.Time = $_.Time -as [datetime] } just enough?

Comment: @IngovandenBersselaar Because you're just modifying the value of a property - why would that produce any output?

Comment: Ah, I think I get it, I figured if I modify the value I can call on it later and it accepts the value as a datetime format value, but adding the $_ afterwards does that part if I understand correctly.

Comment: No, `$_` simply outputs the object that we received as input (and then modified). When you see a bare value expression like `$_`, PowerShell interprets it as `Write-Output $_` - you're simply telling `ForEach-Object`: output the input object after modifying it.